# Creating a "Ruffle" Shape with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm new to geometry nodes, and despite how simple it seemed initially, I couldn't figure out how to create a mesh of this topology using them.

[image: Example of the ruffle mesh]

The overall objective is to have multiple instances of this mesh going along a curve, but by far the hardest part is figuring out how to make a mesh like this from scratch, if it's even possible.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible to solve this completely procedurally with *Geometry Nodes*. I wouldn't recommend it though, because that means a bunch of nodes and is a logic game that is relatively rigid. Better would be to create the basic shape as a mesh, provide certain points as a vertex group, and simply scale/move them with *Geometry Nodes*. It would be even easier to use *Shape Keys* for this.

Comment: Do you want the question to be reopened? However, I would then recommend editing it accordingly so that it only refers to the topic of procedurally creating this shape, because the second part (array and bending the mesh) is actually done with the linked answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably getting a bit too procedural-happy here, but if you may, please reopen it, just to see if anybody would be willing to take a stab at it! I'll go ahead and edit the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure whether i understood your 3d model correctly, but if you have too much time, you can do it like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have slightly [less time than @Chris](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274297/35559) :D, (this version is Y along, X across,) you can extrude a grid's central panels, delete all Y-facing faces, and make the XYZ scales of the top points of the extrusion all functions of Y:

[image]

The ranges of the *Float Curve* nodes have been set to: `X: -1->1`, and `Y: 0->3`

[image]

If you were playing node golf, you could have crunched all the curves into one *RGB Curves* node, with ranges mapped.

.. but as @quellenform comments, it's rigid.. unless re-use is for some reason likely, probably better to model externally.